# Browser resize + slideToggle not working well together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive site & would like to do some slideToggle effects on a mobile version, keeping the desktop site with fully shown text & no effects. I'm using modernizr for my media queries, and it works only when you refresh the page after the window has been resized. It all goes bonkers when you just resize & try to interact with it, though. It's not easy to describe, so please check below link:

[www.lastpixel.ie/new/test.php](http://www.lastpixel.ie/new/test.php)

1. resize browser -> refresh -> click on the item -> works perfect
2. resize browser -> click on the item -> constant slideToggle

What is causing such a hiccup?

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Item 1</h2>
                <div class="icn"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Item 2</h2>
                <div class="icn"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Item 3</h2>
                <div class="icn"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-title">
                <h2 class="subtitle">Item 4</h2>
                <div class="icn"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function doneResizing() {

  if(Modernizr.mq('screen and (max-width: 870px)')) {

    $('.item-title').click(function (el) {

        $(this).next().slideToggle();

        $(this).toggleState(function (el) {

            el.animate({
                backgroundColor: "#333",
                'color': "#fff"
            }, 500);

            }, function (el) {
            el.animate({
                backgroundColor: "#e7e7e7",
                'color': "#000"
            }, 500);
        });

    });

}

  }

  var id;
  $(window).resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(id);
      id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 0);
  });

  doneResizing();

});
```

Comment: Your site as error, fix it firstly

Answer (score 1):

You posted the JS you embedded in the page but it also looks like you have main.js included which has some of the same functionality as the JS you embedded. My bet is that this has something to do with your problem, but I can't test it myself.

Comment: good call! I've disabled it, which fixed the slide-up-and-down madness. It still isn't working 100% though, the slideToggle effect isn't disabled when you resize it to desktop size ...

Comment: I would try keeping the click function separate from the doneresizing function and just add or remove a class in doneresizing, thereby ensuring the function doesn't get left enabled.